# Minimization of a quaradic-like expression when calculating the generating functional for free Dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, grassmann-numbers

The generating functional for a free Dirac field is 
$$Z_0[\eta,\bar{\eta}]=\int D\bar{\psi}D\psi \mathrm{exp}\{i\int [\bar{\psi}(x)S^{-1}\psi(x)+\bar{\eta}(x)\psi(x)+\bar{\psi}(x)\eta(x)]dx\}$$
where $S^{-1}=i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m$, $\bar{\eta}(x)$ is the source for $\psi(x)$ and $\eta(x)$ is the source for $\bar{\psi}(x)$.

1. If we put the exponent to be 
   $$Q(\psi,\bar{\psi})=\bar{\psi}S^{-1}\psi+\bar{\eta}\psi+\bar{\psi}\eta$$
   Then how do we prove that $Q$ is actually minimized when $\psi=-S\eta$ and $\bar{\psi}=-\bar{\eta}S$?
2. My second question is that is the "quadratic-like" expression $Q(\psi,\bar{\psi})$ really a quadratic form?

Comment: 1.If minimizing grassman valued function has a meaning at all, then just do partial differentiations and set them to be 0; 2. it certainly is formally a quadratic form, what's your definition of "really a quadratic form"?

Comment: because normally the quadratic form is defined to be $x^TSx$ for some column vector $x$, which is different from what we have in $Q$ since $\gamma^0$ is involved.

Comment: $\psi,\bar{\psi}$ are treated as independent variables, so the correct analogy here is $y^TSx$, which is still a quadratic form.